# Pandas dataframe how can I remove rows by comparing regex output of column A and B

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, regex, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns , both columns contain strings

I want to delete rows where the regex match of column B (Resources) does not match column A (ServicePlan) for a named capture group "termduration" in the regex result.

Data:

```
                    ServicePlan                         Resources
0  Plan A (CSP COM BAS 1YR ANN)  Resource A (CSP COM BAS 1YR ANN)
1  Plan A (CSP COM BAS 1YR ANN)  Resource B (CSP COM BAS 1YR ANN)
2  Plan A (CSP COM BAS 1YR ANN)  Resource C (CSP COM BAS 6YR ANN)
```

I tried the following but I get a type error. I am struggling to compare the regex named capture group result between two strings.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
e_name = r'(?P<name>.*)\((?P<product>[A-Z]{3})\s(?P<type>[A-Z]{3})\s?(?P<baseattach>BAS|ADD|ATT|SWS)?\s?(?P<telco_overusage>OVG)?\s?(?P<termduration>[A-Z0-9]{3})?\s?(?P<billing>[A-Z0-9]{3})\)$'
name_re = re.compile(e_name)


data = {'ServicePlan': ["Plan A (CSP COM BAS 1YR ANN)","Plan A (CSP COM BAS 1YR ANN)","Plan A (CSP COM BAS 1YR ANN)"],
        'Resources': ["Resource A (CSP COM BAS 1YR ANN)","Resource B (CSP COM BAS 1YR ANN)","Resource C (CSP COM BAS 6YR ANN)"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
df[~(name_re.findall(df['ServicePlan'].astype(str))[0]['termduration']).ne(name_re.findall(df['Resource'].astype(str))[0]['termduration'])]
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pandas.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df = df[df['ServicePlan'].str.extract(name_re, expand=False)['termduration']
        .eq(df['Resources'].str.extract(name_re, expand=False)['termduration'])]
print(df)
```

---

```
                   ServicePlan                         Resources
0  Plan A (CSP COM BAS 1YR ANN)  Resource A (CSP COM BAS 1YR ANN)
1  Plan A (CSP COM BAS 1YR ANN)  Resource B (CSP COM BAS 1YR ANN)
```

Comment: hi there, would you know how can I also keep rows where the optional capture group "termduration" is not found in column B and A for that row? right now those are excluded.

Comment: Hi again, I got it, I used .fillna('None') it works then.